# Clicking WhatsApp pop-up with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I want to click (or press enter) to a button for allowing the WhatsApp API to open the application

[image]

I've tried everything to click or give enter as input, however all of selenium functions I've seen so far require something to identify the element, which doesn't seem to be available for this particular pop-up nowhere in the HTML.

So far what I've tried is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=573111111111")
time.sleep(2)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Open WhatsApp"]')
element.click()
driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[text()="Open WhatsApp"]"}
```

This works for normal pop-ups, but not in this case. Maybe the problem is that this popup is not part of the HTML but part of google chrome, in that case how can I select such window and press enter/click?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but you should probably check on the source code, if that 'pop up' is inside of an iFrame, if that is the case you will need to use ```driver.switch_frame()``` method to get inside the frame and find the element you need.

Answer (score 1):

I have provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62571293/7409921)  for opening application using chrome with selenium for python, and it might be helpful to you.