# Open Application (such as zoom.us) with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to use pure selenium webdriver to open a zoom link in Chrome and then redirect me to the zoom.us application.

When I execute this:

```
from selenium import webdriver


def main():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://zoom.us/j/000-000-000")


main()
```

I receive a pop-up saying

```
https://zoom.us wants to open this application.
```

and I must press a button titled `open zoom.us` to open the app.

Is there a way to press this pop-up button through selenium. Or, is there some other way to open zoom from chromedriver?

NOTE: I only want to use selenium. I have been able to implement pyautogui to click on the button but that is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Java:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Solution for Python:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Comment: This ordinary way of dealing with alerts does not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of duplicated questions regarding this issue. Here is one of [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154160/how-to-click-on-open-application-alert-using-selenium), and it is quite sure that selenium is not capable of achieving such job since it only interacts with the chrome page. I previously encountered this issue as well and here is my solution to it. It might look really unprofessional, but fortunately it works.

The logic of my solution is to change the setting of chrome in order to skip the popup and directly open the application you want. However, the Chrome team has removed this feature in the latter version for some reasons, and we need to get it back manually. Then, we know that everytime when selenium starts to do the thing it opens a new Chrome page with NO customized settings just like the incognito page. Therefore we need to do something to let selenium opened a Chrome page with your customized setting, so that we can make sure that the popup, which we changed manually to skip, can be skipped successfully.

1. Type the following code in your terminal.

   ```
   defaults write com.google.Chrome ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox -bool true
   ```

   This enables you to change the setting of skipping popups, which is the feature Chrome team removed.
2. Restart Chrome,and open the zoom (or whatever application) page to let the popup display. If you do the 1st step correctly you will be able to see there is a checkbox shown next to the "Open Zoom.us" saying if you check it chrome will open this application without asking, that is, to skip the popup for this application.
3. Now we need to let selenium open the Chrome with our customized setting. To do this, type "chrome://version" in the search tab of your ordinary Chrome (Not automated page opened by selenium). Go to "Profile Path", and copy this path without the last word "default". For example:

   ```
   /Users/MYNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
   ```

   This is my profile path, but I only copy everything except the last word Default, so this is what I need to copy.

   ```
   /Users/MYNAME/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/
   ```

   This is for Mac users, but for Windows only the path is different(starts with C:// or something), steps are same.
4. ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

    option = Options()
    option.add_argument('THE PATH YOU JUST COPIED')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER', options=option)

    driver.get("google.com") #Or anything else
   ```

   We use "options" to let selenium open a page with our customized profile. Now you will see selenium opens a Chrome page with all your account profile, settings, and it just appears like your ordinary chrome page.
5. Run your code. But before that, remember to quit ALL CHROME sessions manually. For Mac, make sure that there is no dot under Chrome icon indicating that Chrome is not running for any circumstances. THIS STEP IS CRITICAL otherwise selenium will open a chrome page and it just stops there.

Here are all the steps. Again, this solution is vert informal and I personally don't think it is a "solution" to this problem. I will try to figure out a better way of achieving this in the future. But I still posted this as an alternative simply because I guess it might be helpful to some extent for somebody just like me. Hope it works for you, and good luck.